# Number of rows in 40GB tar.gz file without uncompressing it?

Tags: python, csv, gzip, tar

I have over 40 gb tar.gz file at https://ghtstorage.blob.core.windows.net/downloads/mysql-2016-06-16.tar.gz
How can I find the number of rows in the CSV file that is compressed inside this tar.gz file without uncompressing the entire file which might be in 100+ GBs?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do it in Python specifically?

Comment: You just can't, but you may want the producer to add that piece of information to the name so that you don't have to figure it out yourself.

Comment: To count the rows, you'll need to uncompress every part of the file at some point. You might be able to work on it in chunks though, rather than uncompressing the whole file at once. Pick a chunk size that fits in memory and the size of the file is less of an issue. Is this what you're asking for (how to process a `.tar.gz` file in chunks)?

Comment: Yes, I need to do it in Python @Juhana.

Comment: @Blckknght: How can I uncompress .tar.gz file in chunks, read the data, and write that to a CSV in an iterative manner?

Answer (score 3):

If there is only one csv file in that tar.gz, you could do this as a bash one-liner:

`tar -zxOf mysql-2016-06-16.tar.gz | wc -l`

It uses tar to extract all the files in the archive to standard output (-O, capital o, not zero), and wc to count the lines.

If there is more files, and only want that one file, you can count the lines in that file like this:

`tar -zxOf mysql-2016-06-16.tar.gz mysql-2016-06-16/commit_comments.csv| wc -l`

Here's how to list all files in the archive:

`tar -zlf mysql-2016-06-16.tar.gz`

CSV files usually have a header, so remove one line per file and you have the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

> without uncompressing the entire file which might be in 100+ GBs

I suppose you mean without extracting the file to disk first. Here's a Python approach to achieve this:

```
import tarfile as tf
import gzip as gz
from StringIO import StringIO
infile = '/path/to/mysql-2016-06-16.tar.gz'
def linecount(infile, member):
    lc = 0
    with gz.GzipFile(infile) as zipf:
        with tf.TarFile(fileobj=zipf) as tarf:
            dataf = tarf.extractfile(member)
            while dataf.readline():
               lc += 1 
            dataf.close()       
    return lc
print linecount(infile, 'test.csv')
```

> it say's "filename 'test.csv' not found".

To know what members the tar file has:

```
def listmembers(infile):
    with gz.GzipFile(infile) as zipf:
        with tf.TarFile(fileobj=zipf) as tarf:
            return list(m.name for m in tarf)
```

To count the lines of all files in the tarfile:

```
for member in listmembers(infile):
    print member, linecount(infile, member)
```

Before you start it will be useful to [know how tar files are structured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#File_format).

Comment: Does this perform on-the-fly decompression or it extracts into a temporary file?

Comment: this is in-memory on-the-fly decompression.

Comment: Thank you @miraculixx for the code. I think, I am almost there, but it say's "filename 'test.csv' not found". I am new to Python :(. What should I do next?

Comment: @miraculixx: It still say's "filename 'test.csv' not found". Do I need to supply any information for "member" in the above code? Thanks!

Comment: I could tell you but I think you will benefit much more from actually thinking through my quite complete example code. You are on the right track. _Hint:_ I didn't actually download your file, I made my own `tar.gz` and included a `test.csv`.

Comment: Ok, I will try to understand. Thanks for sharing the detailed code @miraculixx. Actually, I learned Python just 2 weeks ago and am taking baby steps to learn from you guys. Really appreciate your patience!